# Android Studio does not install SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, sdk

oh god i hate SO MUCH this sdk thing.
I just want to build a game made with Unity, i need androids sdk.
sdk manager alone is in console so not really for standard human. i tried but it didn't worked. the sdkmanager console open and close at speed of light.
I downloaded Android Studio to use the UI and the sdk manager embeded.
I deleted anything related to Android to make a clean install.
At startup, Android Studio ask for wish component i would like to download.
It show me all what i want but i CAN NOT CLICK on these damn things.
[image: see, i can't]
Then after installation it says there is no SDK (really?) and it show me what is missing but refuse to install it. still can't click. 
I deleted all config files and reinstalled and retried 5 or 6 times.
just want to smash the screen. at least 5 hours lost and it goes on.
Everytime i do SDK it always goes wrong. its a nightmare.

Comment: Did you try changing sdk location?

Comment: Did you try removing `C:\Android\sdk` and try again? Though I think this is not necessary.

Comment: ok i recreated the android/sdk folder again, and it worked. now i can click. strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you want install it for Unity - you just need to install Android Studio. Then just go to Unity, click to "SDK: download" and it will automaticly download it.

Comment: i don't get what you mean, Unity->preferences->external tools ? if i click on download sdk it open the android studio download page. not usefull ?

Answer (score 0):

So for me the answer was to delete and recreate Android/sdk folder. make sur it is empty.